# Trying to set X Axis to" mm:ss"

Tags: canvasjs

I'm trying to make the X Axis at my charts show  scale that looks like - "minutes:seconds" (mm:ss)
but all I could do is make it a scale of year and monthes by:

```
new Date();
```

I really couln't find any guide that I understood...
This is my JS code:

```
window.onload = function () {
  let d = new Date();
  let secondsString = d.getSeconds();
  let minString = d.getMinutes();
  var totalTime = `${minString}${secondsString}` * 1;


    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {

      title:{
      text: "Coins"
      },
       data: [{        
        type: "spline",
        name: "Bitcoin",
        showInLegend: true,
        dataPoints: [
       {x: new Date(), y: 1200},
      {x: new Date(), y: 1300},
      {x: new Date(), y: 1400} 
        ]
      },       
      ]
    });

    chart.render();
  }
```

How do I change the x Axis string ?

Currectly it looks like this:
[image]

The x Axis scale shows 2,834. I want it to be: 28:34.

Answer (score 1):

Setting [valueFormatString](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/axisx/valueformatstring/) to "HH:mm" should work fine in your case.

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  title:{
    text: "Coins"
  },
  axisX: {
   valueFormatString: "HH:mm"
  },
  data: [{        
    type: "spline",
    name: "Bitcoin",
    showInLegend: true,
    dataPoints: [
      {x: new Date(2019, 09, 17, 02, 15, 20), y: 1200},
      {x: new Date(2019, 09, 17, 08, 15, 20), y: 1300},
      {x: new Date(2019, 09, 17, 14, 15, 20), y: 1400} 
    ]
  },       
 ]
});

chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
```